# Cannot use placeholders for the names of schema objects in dynamic SQL statements

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mysql2

I am dynamically creating mysql statements in Node JS using the mysql2 library to retrieve and store data,

I recently began getting a bug 'Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 16382)'

After doing some digging I realised I was not using placeholders within my statements and thus cached statements were not closed, as I begun changing my code to utilise the placeholders to prevent this I also realised that you can not use placeholders for the names of schema objects.

An example of many is:

let obj = await pool.execute(`select * from`  + config_schema + `.parameters`);

Firstly I am unsure if this will be contributing to my prepared statements, and secondly if there is a better way to do what I am trying to achieve.

Any help/advice is greatly apricated!

Answer (score 0):

Using `.query()` instead of `.execute` resolved this issue as `.execute()` in this library will prepare statements.